# DropdownButton cause null item exception

Tags: flutter

DropdownButton cause null exception as i am passing string variable  in value name parameter.

```
  String diseases = "Select a disease";

DropdownButton<String>(
    value: diseases,
    items: model.diseases
   .map((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<
    String>(
    value: value,
    child: Text(value),
     );
     }).toList(),
     onChanged: (d) {
     setState(() {
     diseases = d;
     print(
     diseases.toString());
     });
     },
     )
```

It works fine if I used first selected element from the array **value: diseases**, by **value: model.diseases[0]**, and it also works fine if I hotreload after changing model.diseases[0] to "diseases" in value

> ════════ Exception Caught By widgets library
>   ═══════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown
>   building Builder(dirty): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
>   Failed assertion: line 608 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty ||
>   value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) => item.value
>   == value).length == 1': is not true.
>
> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we
>   should provide substantially more information in this error message to
>   help you determine and fix the underlying cause. In either case,
>   please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
>   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

Comment: I first check if (model.diseases!=null?Dropdownbutton(....) .it not null , i checked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because the default value you provided does not exist on the list of values, if you want to show label in dropdown menu before any value is selected set the initial value as null and use hint property of the dropdownmenu widget

```
    String diseases;

DropdownButton<String>(
    hint: Text("Select a disease"),
    value: diseases,
    items: model.diseases
   .map((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<
    String>(
    value: value,
    child: Text(value),
     );
     }).toList(),
     onChanged: (d) {
     setState(() {
     diseases = d;
     print(
     diseases.toString());
     });
     },
     )
```

Comment: you are right ,  need to set inital value null, but really strange it is.

Comment: The combination of hint + null for value does the trick. Without hint, setting value to null will throw an exception.